# Oracle to Hadoop Migration

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any function in Oracle that is not available (or different) in Spark-SQL? If yes how can we deal with it?
For example, Date functions are different. Is there any function that are yet to be added in Spark.

Comment: In general, community uses `sqoop` to import the data to HDFS in one time and then incrementally. Do you have any requirements to process the data before writing it to HDFS?

Comment: what do you mean by any function ?? if you use Spark SQL, you will connect directly by JDBC to run SQL statements in the database. I would not recommend it, because it is better to use Spark SQL against Hadoop to get the benefits to use parallel  processing, so the first step should be store your Oracle tables as Hive Tables. Normally, Sqoop is the easiest way to do that, but if you want high level performance, an option is to use in-build Oracle Hadoop connectors

Comment: Do I take it that you are using Oracle SQL now, but want to convert to Hadoop and Spark-SQL going forward?